# onclick show div for some second and on other click increase the div size and also dont hide it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Show a div0 onclicking button1 for 10 sec then if someone clicks on button0 which is inside the div0, increase the size of the of div0 and also remove the timer or set custom time for hiding.

***I want to know -***
how to set custom time for hiding div0 by clicking the button0.
also how to show div0 permanently.

here is my code

### HTML

```
<!-- its the hidden div which has to appear -->  
<div class="div0"><button onclick="openAll()"><button> button0</button></div>                 
<!-- its the button1 -->  
<button onclick="hidDiv()">button1</button>
```

### CSS

```
.div0{width:100px;height:100px}
```

### Javascript

```
function hidDiv(){
var nb = document.getElementsByClassName('div0');
 nb.className = "show";
 var timeOut = setTimeout(function(){ 
            nb.className = "hide";
 },5000 );  
}  

function openAll(){
var nb = document.getElementsByClassName('div0')[0];
 nd.style.width = "300px";
 nd.style.height = "300px"; 
}
```

Comment: *"how to set custom time for hiding"* - Isn't that just a matter of setting the second parameter of `setTimeout()` to the time you want? *"how to show div0 permanently."* - Isn't that just a matter of *not hiding it*?

Comment: i m beginner to javascript.

Comment: Your button typo , </buttom></div>   use button instead of buttom

Comment: sorry bro corrected .

Answer (score 0):

inside timeout use

```
display="none";
```

and in below style add

```
nd.style.disply=block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me breakdown your question into DOM (Document Object Model) and Javascript.

The DOM part is the way components of HTML page interact with your code, which doesn't have to be Javascript (though usually it is).

Javascript is a language, which you can run outside the browser like any other language, but most commonly it is the one in which you program browser snippets of code.

So, now for the DOM part. your page has a div and two buttons.
The appearance of your DOM objects are controlled by CSS. for example, if you wanted to hide a div you would say:

```
<div style="display:none">You will not see this </div>
```

If you wanted to access this element in your Javascript, you need to do something like this:

```
var everyDivInDocument = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

because you can have more than one div, you will always get an array from this call. if there are no divs, the array would be empty. if there are for example 3 divs, the array would have three members.

There are other ways for getting elements from DOM, some I list for you, so you know what to Google.

```
var manyElementsCanHaveTheSameClass = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
var usuallyOnlyOneElementHasAnId = document.getElementById("myid");
var youCanAlsoSearchByCSS = document.querySelector("div[someAttribute]");
```

Once you have your DOM Element, you can hide it.

```
everyDivInDocument[0].style.display="none"; //hides the first div found
```

OK. know that we have covered this, let's talk about DOM Events. onclick is a DOM event that you already know. the `hidDiv()` function is called a handler. let's use that to show the div as per code you provided:

```
function hidDiv(){
  var nb = document.getElementsByClassName('div0');
  nb[0].style.display="";
  nb[0].timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function(){ 
        nb[0].style.display = "none";
        nb[0].timeoutHandler = null;
  },5000 );  
}
```

So, the difference is the index of 0 to get the first member of the array, then set the style (I didn't change the className because I don't see any such class in your CSS, but you may as well do that if you define the CSS class).

Now, let's say that clicking on the other button should cancel the timeout event.

```
function openAll(){
    var nb = document.getElementsByClassName('div0')[0];
        if(nb.timeoutHandler) clearTimeout(nb.timeoutHandler);
        nb.timeoutHandler = null;
        nb.style.width = "300px";
        nd.style.height = "300px"; 
}
```

You see the difference? a var defined inside a function scopes to that function, so it won't exist once that function returns and you can't cancel your timeout. but if you put it somewhere that you can find it, like attach it to the DOM object it is monitoring, then you can cancel it later.

Hope that makes sense.